# Getting Cpu Speed using Command Prompt in windows 8

Tags: cpu-speed

I need to get the CPU speed in Cpu tab in Task manager i.e at What Frequency CPU is running? . How Can I get that speed using command prompt?

Comment: http://www.windows-commandline.com/get-cpu-processor-information-command/

Comment: You can get max cpu frequency using ```wmic cpu get MaxClockSpeed```